# How to get argument when POSTed to URL using Perl (Mojolicious)

Tags: perl, post, iframe, mojolicious, two-factor-authentication

I am setting up duo two-factor authentication in a perl web application (using mojolicious). I am new to perl so this may be a simple answer.

I have everything set up except I need to verify the response by doing the following:
"After the user authenticates (e.g. via phone call, SMS passcode, etc.) the IFRAME will generate a signed response called sig_response and POST it back to the post_action URL. Your server-side code should then call verify_response() to verify that the signed response is legitimate."

In perl, how can you call for sig_response, is there a module? Below is in example using python: 
    `sig_response = self.get_argument("sig_response") # for example (if using Tornado: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/documentation.html)`

Duo Web: https://duo.com/docs/duoweb

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this `sig_response` is just a value that's POSTed to your response handler. When you created the URL to show in the iframe, it had a `post_action` parameter. That's the endpoint in your application that handles the user coming back from the iframe.

You need to build a route in Mojo for that. There, you need to look at the parameters you are receiving in the POST body. I don't know if it's form-data or something else, like JSON. It doesn't really say in the documentation. I suggest you dump the parameters, and if that doesn't show it, dump the whole request body.

Once you have that `sig_response` parameter, you need to call [the `verify_response` function](https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_perl/blob/master/DuoWeb.pm#L144) that duo's library provides and look at the return value.

If you have not done it yet, get the SDK at https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_perl. It's not a full distribution. You can either clone the whole thing or just download the pm file from their github and put it in the `lib` directory of your application. Then `use` it like you would any other module. Since it doesn't export anything, you need to use the fully qualified name to call the `verify_response` function.

The whole thing might look something like this untested code:

```
post '/duo_handler' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    my $sig_request = $c->param('sig_response');
    my $user = DuoWeb::verify_response($ikey, $skey, $akey, $sig_request);
    if ($user) { 
        # logged in
    } else {
        # not logged in
    }
};
```

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I don't know this service. I have only quickly read the documentation you linked, and taken a look at their Perl SDK, which they should really put on CPAN.</sub>

Comment: There is also a module https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Duo on CPAN that is related, but it's not official. I don't know what it does as I am not familiar with _duo_ at all.